After element appearing Infront of the parent element
In this code I am trying to make a navigation bar for a dashboard,
I went to add a glow effect under my current navbar which has a gray background but when adding the pseudo-element it docent appear bellow the current navbar, it appears above and removes the grey background entirely so I played around with z-index to fix it but it didn't fix the positioning, In the final product I just want a navbar with a grey background and a glow underneath that has a simple glow effect under it using the (::after) element.
Here is the code that I am working on for reference I use Brave browser (built over google). Thank you in advance for any help!
feather.replace()

* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&display=swap');
body {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #b0b0b0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}

.navbar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(15px);
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #4285F4 0%, #9b72cb 27%, #d96570 55%);
}

.navbar__menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar__item {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar__link {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 5.5rem;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
}

.navbar__link span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-3rem);
  margin-left: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #6d8eff;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  transition: 250ms ease all;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar__link:hover,
.navbar:not(:hover) .navbar__link:focus {
  color: #6d8eff;
}

.navbar__link:hover span,
.navbar:not(:hover) .navbar__link:focus span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.navbar__item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background: #6d8eff;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  transition: 250ms cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.1, 1.2) all;
}

.navbar__item:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

@keyframes gooeyEffect {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.5, 1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}

.navbar__item:hover::before {
  animation: gooeyEffect 250ms 1;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="home"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="book"></i><span>Subjects</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="align-center"></i><span>Notes</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="check-circle"></i><span>Tasks</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="bar-chart"></i><span>Statistics</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="help-circle"></i><span>Help</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#" class="navbar__link"><i data-feather="settings"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>


I have run your snippet and the ::after pseudo element is below the icons in the navbar. I removed the z-index: -1 and set its opacity to 1 and saw only the 'glow' - i.e. your code seems to work fine. Can you say what browser you are using?
